# using Jmeter to test Documentum D2 Application

Tags: jmeter, documentum

i am doing performence tests using Jmeter on Documentum's d2 application
I've recorded a login and logout using blaze meter
All the requests are in green but i get an error in the response body
"Missing context(s) from session, re-connection required" ,
Anyone know whats happening? If there are any special params that needs to be passed

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay recording test without doing prior [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of the dynamic parameters.

You should design your test as follows:

1. [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - open login page

   - Extract each and every dynamic parameter using suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. HTTP Request - perform login. Here you need to substitute recorded hard-coded parameters with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) generated in the previous request

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan